# When does angular destroy a directive instance?

Tags: angularjs

I created a directive, which binds to `$stateChangeSuccess` events in link function:

```
module.exports = angular.module("titlePanel", [])
    .directive("titlePanel", titlePanel);

function titlePanel($state, $rootScope, $parse, $interpolate) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: false,
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: template,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        // some actions
        // ...

        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(){
            console.log("State change success happened on titlePanel");
        });
    }
}
```

This directive is used only at some pages of my site. What surprises me is that when I transition from state that contains this directive's instance to a state that doesn't contain it anymore, directive still responds to `$stateChangeSuccess` event and executes `console.log()`.

I believe, I misunderstand the chronological order of events upon transferring to a certain state (I use `ui-router`). I thought it is as follows:

1. ui-router starts switching to a new state
2. it resolves and loads dependencies of new state's controller
3. it instantiates new controller
4. it traverses through the code of new controller's template and detects directives within it
5. it compiles those directives if they were not already compiled and stored in module registry
6. it creates directive instances by creating directive scopes and calling `link` linking function
7. it destroys the previous state, previous controller/scope and instances of directives, built for the previous controller
8. it emits $stateChangeSuccess

I am probably wrong somewhere. Can you describe the correct order of events?

Comment: try changing to `scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess"`.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for suggestion, but I can't because I use `controllerAs` syntax. And I'm interested in theoretical aspect of the question.

Comment: doesn't matter that use `controllerAs`. `scope` is still needed for events and watches. I'm not sure about sequence either but my guess is scope will be destroyed before a rootscope $on gets removed...if it even does. I don't think that it ever gets removed from $rootScope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directives are destroyed once they are no longer represented in the DOM.  (They do persist if they're not visible, hence `ng-show=false` will hide but not destroy the directive; `ng-if=false` will destroy it.)

But:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(){
    console.log("State change success happened on titlePanel");
});
```

This attaches the event to `rootScope`, which persists throughout the lifespan of the application, even after the directive is gone.

You can prevent this by either explicitly detaching the event on the directive's 'destroy' method:

```
var unbinder = $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
    console.log("State change success happened on titlePanel");
});
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    unbinder();
});
```

...or, better, by attaching the event to the directive's scope rather than the root scope, so it will be cleaned up automatically.  (It's generally good practice to avoid using root scope when not absolutely necessary: instead bind events to the directive they belong to, or to a shared factory or service devoted to that purpose.)

Comment: Damn, I'm stupid. Got dazzled by angular whistles and bells and forgot that event handler doesn't depend on where it was created.

Comment: I binded to `scope` of the directive and still get `console.log()`, when I transition to next state, so directive instance is destroyed after `$stateChangeSuccess`. This sounds logical, cause `$stateChangeSuccess` receives `fromState` as one of the arguments: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki.

Comment: hm, right, I'm rusty on ui-router (and see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2485, I'm not sure what the current correct behavior is there).   You might have better luck with `$viewContentLoaded` instead? or else destroy the event manually.